# How to shoot ball to Touch X position Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a ball on a ground, and when touching the screen I want to shoot it to the X position of the Touch. Do you have any suggestions?

This is the code I have so far:

```
public Rigidbody Ball;
public float Speed = 50f;



void FixedUpdate () {

    if(ClickDone == false){
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)){
            ClickDone = true;
            Ball.velocity = transform.forward * Speed;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html and https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html

Comment: @derHugo can you please write an example of the code? because I am beginner and honestly I didn't understand these docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is your new code :

```
using UnityEngine;

public class GoToTouch : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera cam;//put your main camera here
    public float speed;//Speed of movement
    Vector3 LastTouch;
    void Start()
    {
        LastTouch = Vector3.zero;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        //We check for new touches etch frame
        if (Input.touchCount> 0)
            LastTouch = Input.touches[0].rawPosition;
        //We move towards the last touch
        if(LastTouch != Vector3.zero)transform.position=
    Vector3.Lerp(transform.position,cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(LastTouch),speed*Time.DeltaTime);
    }
}
```

what is important for you to look at is the 
ScreenToWorldPoint function LastTouch holds the actual pixel the user touched
after ScreenToWorldPoint you get the position that the pixel he touched represent in the 
world. Good luck learning !

Comment: Thank you, but I click and nothing is happening!

Comment: Did you check it on a your phone ? did you link the camera ? did you set the speed to what you want ?

Comment: I've linked the camera and changed speed, but I want to test it on unity and see how it looks.

Comment: The problem is that touch only works on mobile phones not PC so you need to test it on your phone, I suggest you use the unity remote app

Comment: So there's no way to make it works on mobile and desktop?

Comment: I've tested it on mobile and when clicking the ball fly to the space, I want it to go forward but to the touch direction

Comment: I don't really get what direction space is . but try to change the ScreenToWorldPoint(LastTouch) to ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(LastTouch.x , LastTouch.y, cam.nearClipPlane)) , also maybe a little screenshot of your scene can help solving this . I suggest you use BlueStacks it's an Android emulator unfortunately unity doesn't have one built in but if you don't want to get a mobile phone into your workflow it can do the job.